# Trouble saving a model within a view with backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js

I've got a view setup that shows a couple of input fields. When either of the fields is changed I want to save the changed value for the model.

Here's my view:

```
  EditWordView = Backbone.View.extend({
tagName: 'article',
className: 'word',

initialize: () ->
  _.bindAll this, 'render'

  this.template = _.template($('#edit-word-template').html())
  this.model.bind 'change', this.render
,
events: {
  "change input": "changed"
},

render: () ->
  this.model.fetch()
  $word = $('#word')
  $word.empty()
  renderContent = this.template(this.model.toJSON())
  $(this.el).html(renderContent)
  $word.append(this.el)
  this
,
changed: (event) ->
  changed = event.currentTarget
  value = $("#" + changed.id).val()
  obj = {}
  obj[changed.id] = value
  this.model.save(obj)
,
save: (event) ->
  this.model.save()
  view = new WordView({model: this.model})
  view.render()
  event.preventDefault()
})
```

And here's the model:

```
SpellingWord = Backbone.Model.extend({
url: () ->
  '/spelling_words/' + this.id
})
```

When I get to the changed event and try to save the model

```
this.model.save(obj)
```

has no effect

The set(attrs) method is called on the model within the save method in backbone.js but the value is never changed in the model and hence never persisted back to the backend. Is this something to do with the scope of the this.model object?

If I call

```
this.model.set(obj)
```

before this.model.save(obj) then value of the model's attributes never changes.

set(attrs) works within the console for objects so I'm a bit stumped as to why it won't in my view.

Ideas?

EDIT>>>>>>>

I've dug into the backbone code and in the **save** method **set** is called:

```
save : function(attrs, options) {
  options || (options = {});
  if (attrs && !this.set(attrs, options)) return false;
  var model = this;
  var success = options.success;
```

After the this.set(attrs, options) method is called the attributes of the model aren't changed.

Now, looking in the **set** method I don't see how the attribute is supposed to be changed when it's actually changing the **now** variable?

```
var now = this.attributes, escaped = this._escapedAttributes;
// Run validation.
if (!options.silent && this.validate && !this._performValidation(attrs, options)) return false;
// Check for changes of `id`.
if (this.idAttribute in attrs) this.id = attrs[this.idAttribute];
// We're about to start triggering change events.
var alreadyChanging = this._changing;
this._changing = true;
// Update attributes.
for (var attr in attrs) {
  var val = attrs[attr];
  if (!_.isEqual(now[attr], val)) {
    now[attr] = val;
    delete escaped[attr];
    this._changed = true;
   if (!options.silent) this.trigger('change:' + attr, this, val, options);
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, looks like

```
this.model.bind 'change', this.render
```

was calling the render method from inside save, which first did a fetch and overwrote my changes. The save then didn't take place because the attributes hadn't been changed.

It was always going to be something like that.....